# Regex find 8 digit from big text

Tags: regex, text, extract, regexp-replace

I have data like this `Your LancerPoint ID number is: 10504139 Your LancerPoint username is: dbrooke CA Resident Status: In State Resident` I need to extract the ID number 10504139 jut that in regex help

regexr.com/5s2q2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case you have another set of numbers like a 10 digit number, you could complement Mayank's answer with more specificity.

```
/(?<=LancerPoint\sID\snumber\sis:\s)\d{8}(?=\s)/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\d{8}`

Here \d is for matching digit.

{8} is for matching exactly 8 of them.

Comment: What about the username?

Comment: Bro what is the code to extract the username

Comment: Afridy, You can use `(?<=LancerPoint\susername\sis:\s)\w+(?=\s)` for username. Inspired from Carlos's answer